# StrutsConventionSpringJUnit4TestCase request params null

Tags: java, spring, struts2

I'm new to S2 and especially to unit testing the action classes. My problem is that the parameter interceptor is not assigning param values to the action fields during the unit test.

**Full explanation of the problem:**
Using struts2-junit4-plugin 1.7.4 I was not able to use convention plugin and annotated classes. I found a solution to this problem by following [this example](http://www.codeyouneed.com/struts2-convention-spring-junit4/) but if I want to test the action using inteceptors, my action fields are not populated by params interceptor even though I set the params of the MockHttpServletRequest.

I appriciate any input and advice how to solve this problem or even to do action test better way!

Dependencies:

[image]

Test Class:
[Note - second test without the interceptor stack passes the test..]

```
        public class LoginActionTest extends StrutsConventionSpringJUnit4TestCase {

            /**
             * Invoke all interceptors and specify value of action class'
             * domain objects through request parameters.
             * @throws Exception Exception
             */
            @Test
            public void testInterceptorsBySettingRequestParameters() throws Exception {

                ActionProxy proxy = this.getActionProxy("/login");
                request.setParameter("email","test@user.com");
                request.setParameter("password","testuser");

                System.out.println("\n\nInside test class checking request parameters before execute call:\n\n" +
                        "email => " + request.getParameter("email") +
                        "\npassword => " + request.getParameter("password"));

    // EDIT: removed 
                //LoginAction loginAction = (LoginAction) proxy.getAction();

    // changed from
                //String result = loginAction.execute();
                // to

    String result = proxy.execute();

                System.out.println("\n\nInside test class checking request parameters after execute:\n\n" +
                        "email => " + request.getParameter("email") +
                        "\npassword => " + request.getParameter("password"));

                assertEquals("success", result);
            }

            /**
             * Skip interceptors and specify value of action class'
             * domain objects by setting them directly.
             * @throws Exception Exception
             */
            @Test
            public void testLoginActionWhitoutProxy() throws Exception {

                LoginAction testLA = new LoginAction();
                testLA.setEmail("test@user.com");
                testLA.setPassword("testuser");
                testLA.setSession(new HashMap()); // avoid NPE in execute
                String result = testLA.execute();

                assertEquals("Result is NOT what was expected [success] .. ", "success", result);

            }
        } // end class
```

**Console:**

```
    13:06:36,683  INFO StrutsSpringObjectFactory:42 - ... initialized Struts-Spring integration successfully


    Inside test class checking request parameters before execute call:

    email => test@user.com
    password => testuser
    13:06:37,575  INFO ActionSupport:64 - Verifying login details..
    13:06:37,578  INFO ActionSupport:73 - Check user: 

            Login action ([package].bean.User@2e931d05) 
             with these fields: [firstName = test@user.com, lastName = eXuxIn/PXLQ7ou1/w2TaFzs8dtITa8IoMrxLG37oPatYsxPkJm/5CmPlmzPvjZZx]..

            test@user.com eXuxIn/PXLQ7ou1/w2TaFzs8dtITa8IoMrxLG37oPatYsxPkJm/5CmPlmzPvjZZx
    13:06:37,578  INFO ActionSupport:78 - Check request params beeing passed to the local settters: 

            null null






    13:06:37,774  INFO StrutsSpringObjectFactory:42 - ... initialized Struts-Spring integration successfully
    13:06:37,957  INFO ActionSupport:64 - Verifying login details..
    13:06:37,958  INFO ActionSupport:73 - Check user: 

            Login action ([package].bean.User@54d03269) 
             with these fields: [firstName = test@user.com, lastName = eXuxIn/PXLQ7ou1/w2TaFzs8dtITa8IoMrxLG37oPatYsxPkJm/5CmPlmzPvjZZx]..

            test@user.com eXuxIn/PXLQ7ou1/w2TaFzs8dtITa8IoMrxLG37oPatYsxPkJm/5CmPlmzPvjZZx
    13:06:37,958  INFO ActionSupport:78 - Check request params beeing passed to the local settters: 

            test@user.com testuser
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at [package].action.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:83)
        at [package].action.LoginActionTest.testInterceptorsBySettingRequestParameters(LoginActionTest.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

**SOLUTION:**

**Thanks** to @Aleksandr_M for pointing me out to the right direction. 
I checked again this [S2 tutorial site](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/unit-testing.html) where it states:

> ... After that I can call actionProxy.execute(). This causes the Struts 2
>   framework to go through its normal process of Servlet fileter and
>   interceptors for the action identified by the actionProxy (in this
>   case that is the register.action) ...

So I removed the proxy.getAction() and executed proxy instance to force the S2 to go through the normal process.

Additional change was needed to make it work. And here is the test code:

```
        @Test
        public void testInterceptorsBySettingRequestParameters() throws Exception {

    // set request params for the invocationContext in super class
            request.addParameter("email","test@user.com");
            request.addParameter("password","testuser");

    // use proxy from super class to get actionProxy [don't create new instance]        
            proxy = getActionProxy("/login");

    // execute proxy in normal framework process        
            String result = proxy.execute();

    // check result     
            assertEquals("Result is NOT what was expected [success] .. ", "success", result);
        }
```

Comment: You are just calling action method and not executing S2 action.

Comment: Thanks @AleksandrM! Please check my edited question to see if I understood you right. Now i have a second question. It seems like the execute method is not executed now (only result is returned) so should I use it to test the fields only or can I test the execute as well?

Comment: Which result is returned? If it is `input`/`error` then your action isn't called because some errors.

Comment: The returned result is input. I added the action class execute() code to my question..

Comment: Which line gives you a NPE? Are you using modeldriven? If yes stop using it.

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks again for your time and help! I'm digging in and have a bit more study to do to solve this fully but you helped me to go over the bump. I'm closing this thread..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with a similar problem here are some resources that helped me to undestand what's going on in my code..

[struts2-convention-spring-junit4](http://www.codeyouneed.com/struts2-convention-spring-junit4/)

[action-unit-testing-with-struts-2-0](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/java/action-unit-testing-with-struts-2-0)

[action-unit-testing-with-struts-2-0-part-2](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/java/action-unit-testing-with-struts-2-0-part-2)

[unit-testing-struts-2-actions-spring-junit](http://depressedprogrammer.wordpress.com/2007/06/18/unit-testing-struts-2-actions-spring-junit/)

[struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/testing-actions](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/testing-actions.html)

[struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/unit-testing](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/unit-testing.html)